# How can I extract specific elements out of a unstructured list and put them into a dataframe using Python

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a long list of strings and I want to extract only rows that have "Town":"Some City" & "State":"Some State" and then put those values into a dataframe with town and state as column headers. I've copied an extract of the strings below (it excludes the beginning [ and ending ] because the list is really long. Any ideas?

```
'      "IsPayAtLocation": null,',
 '      "IsMembershipRequired": null,',
 '      "IsAccessKeyRequired": null,',
 '      "ID": 1,',
 '      "Title": "Public"',
 '    },',
 '    "UsageCost": "Free",',
 '    "AddressInfo": {',
 '      "ID": 57105,',
 '      "Title": "Somerset North",',
 '      "AddressLine1": "2800 W. Big Beaver Rd",',
 '      "AddressLine2": null,',
 '      "Town": "Troy",',
 '      "StateOrProvince": "MI",',
 '      "Postcode": "48084",',
 '      "CountryID": 2,',
 '      "Country": {',
 '        "ISOCode": "US",'
```

Comment: Not really clear on the input data.. It's a list of lists of strings? If so, what you pasted is the list of lists (because it's missing commas in the outer list and probably a bracket in the beginning)? For the input you provided, what is the output you expect?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. The input is a list of strings with a [ in the beginning.   For the output I would just like to be able to parse through the entire list and extract key:value pairs that have "town":"some town" and "StateOrProvince":Some State" and then be able to put them into a table.                                                            
 '    "AddressInfo": {',
 '      "ID": 57105,',
 '      "Title": "Somerset North",',
 '      "AddressLine1": "2800 W. Big Beaver Rd",',
 '      "AddressLine2": null,',
 '      "Town": "Troy",',
 '      "StateOrProvince": "MI",',

Comment: @TobiaMartens Clarifications to the question should be made as edits to the original post, not as comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
^[^,]*\b(?:Town|State).*$
```

You can use this `re.findall`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/hE4jH0/34

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'^[^,]*\b(?:Town|State).*$', re.MULTILINE)
test_str = "\"UsageCost\"', ' \"Free\",']\n['    \"AddressInfo\"', ' {']\n['      \"ID\"', ' 57105,']\n['      \"Title\"', ' \"Somerset North\",']\n['      \"AddressLine1\"', ' \"2800 W. Big Beaver Rd\",']\n['      \"AddressLine2\"', ' null,']\n['      \"Town\"', ' \"Troy\",']\n['      \"StateOrProvince\"', ' \"MI\",']\n['      \"Postcode\"', ' \"48084\",']\n['      \"CountryID\"', ' 2,']\n['      \"Country\"', ' {']\n['        \"ISOCode\"', ' \"US\",']\n['        \"ContinentCode\"', ' \"NA\",']\n['        \"ID\"', ' 2,']\n['        \"Title\"', ' \"United States\"']"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error under the second quotation mark for p = re.compile(ur'^[^,]*\b(?:Town|State).*$', re.MULTILINE)

Comment: @TobiaMartens Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: @KyleStrand 3.4.3 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (x86_64)| (default, Oct 20 2015, 14:27:51) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)]

Answer (score 0):

- It's easier to extract the towns and states separately.
- You didn't specify into what kind of *table* you want to put the town and state values, so I give an example with a database table.

---

```
strings = [
 '      ...',
 '      "AddressLine2": null,',
 '      "Town": "Troy",',
 '      "StateOrProvince": "MI",',
 '      ...',
 '      "Town": "Troy",',
 '      "StateOrProvince": "MO",',
]
cities = [s.split('"')[3] for s in strings if '"Town":' in s]
states = [s.split('"')[3] for s in strings if '"StateO' in s]
import sqlite3
data = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
data.execute('CREATE TABLE towns (town TEXT, state CHAR(2))')
data.executemany('INSERT INTO towns VALUES (?, ?)', zip(cities, states))
print('town\tstate')
for row in data.execute('SELECT * FROM towns'): print(row[0]+'\t'+row[1])
```